# `TO_CHAR not supported`in jpql

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

When I am running **JPQL** NamedQuery it gives rror Like:

> Syntax error parsing [SELECT empolyee.value From Empolyee empolyee
>   where empolyee.nameId= :value1 and  empolyee.indicator='org_id' and
>   TO_CHAR(empolyee.startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')<= :value2 and
>   (empolyee.endDate is null OR TO_CHAR(empolyee.endDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')>=
>   :value3)]. The right expression is not a valid expression.

I think error is in `TO_CHAR` it is not supported by **JPA** is there any option for `TO_CHAR`in **JPQL**

Comment: Don't compare dates as strings. Pass proper `java.util.Date` or `java.time.LocalDate` instances instead.

Comment: If you are using eclipselink implementation you can use [OPERATOR](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_operator.htm#operator) you can use `OPERATOR('ToChar', empolyee.startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @YCF_L why recommend some vendor specific option when JPA has "FUNCTION" for invoking random SQL functions, and works on all JPA (2.1) providers. Besides which there are better date/time comparison options ...

Comment: thank you  
@YCF_L and @ DN1, @ DN1 can u please tell me how to use "FUNCTION"

Comment: Why? Doesn't the documentation of your JPA provider tell you? This link shows the arguments it takes http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_functions_other

Comment: thank you @YCF_L. it worked for me ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you YCF_L

`OPERATOR` work for me..

```
OPERATOR('ToChar', empolyee.startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')<= :value1
```